# Select count(*) from `pg_table_def` takes minutes on Amazon Redshift

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

Why might a count from `pg_table_def` in Redshift take more than 2 minutes?

I'm debugging a consistently slow query (exceeds a 4 minute timeout) that lists all tables and columns in a certain schema.  However, the slowness is reproducible with the simpler query below:

```
redshift-psql=> SELECT COUNT(*) from pg_table_def;
 count
-------
  5067
(1 row)

Time: 144956.109 ms
```

Comment: I am guessing network plays a role in your case. You need to take a look it from that aspect, I have ran the same query on my Redshift cluster and it took 0.18 seconds

Comment: Also the workload at the same time you are running this query on the cluster might play a role

Comment: You need to understand how WLM works on Redshift - that query time also includes time the query is potentially _queued_ waiting for a query slot. As per above comment, if you have a lot of concurrent queries (or very few WLM slots) then the query could be queued waiting for other queries to complete. Does your cluster have SQA (short query acceleration) enabled?